# What is the meaning of 厚 (thick) in 厚生労働省 (Ministry of Health, Labour and Welfare​)?

Tags: meaning, kanji

The basic meaning of「厚」is thick, large, deep, strong. I also found the meaning kind, cordial. However I wonder why it is at the beginning of the compound「厚生労働省」.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a prior answer points out, 厚生 means "welfare". I'd like to add some sources to that, because I can see where you may have been stuck: how is "thick" related to "welfare", right?

[精選版 日本国語大辞典](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%8E%9A%E7%94%9F-495978):

> 〘名〙 (**「厚」は加える、強くするの意**)
> ① くらしを健康で豊かにすること。古くは政治を行なう人が人民の生活を豊かにすることをいう。
> ※古文真宝笑雲抄（1525）五「福与二恩沢一也。富貴な人は厚生したばかりぞ」 〔書経‐大禹謨〕

If you see the bolded part, the kanji 厚 here brings in the idea of to add/increase, and to make stronger. That's where the sense of "welfare" and "better quality of life" comes in.

This can be further adumbrated by this definition found on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8E%9A%E7%94%9F), the key words 豊か, 増進する:

> 厚 生（こうせい）
> 生活を**豊かにし、健康を守り増進する**こと。

Note that the adjective 厚い is related to this usage:

[jisho.org](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%8E%9A%E3%81%84)

> abundant (​Only applies to 厚い)

[デジタル大辞泉（小学館）](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%8E%9A%E3%81%84/)

> 富んでいる。金持ちだ。
> 「至って―・き御身上の御方はいかが侍らん」〈仮・東海道名所記・六〉

Comment: It seems the word 厚生 itself was taken from a passage in 書経. [[reference](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/厚生省)]

Comment: @aguijonazo Interesting! Thanks for that. I found the original source from which the word was taken 「於！帝念哉！德惟善政，政在養民。水、火、金、木、土、穀，惟修；正德、利用、厚生、惟和。九功惟敘，九敘惟歌。戒之用休，董之用威，勸之以九歌俾勿壞。」《[尚書/大禹謨](https://zh.wikisource.org/zh/%E5%B0%9A%E6%9B%B8/%E5%A4%A7%E7%A6%B9%E8%AC%A8)》 From what I understand, all those four words in that parallel structure follow a verb-noun pattern. So 厚 appears to be a verb in its original sense...

Answer (score -1):

It's merely a component of the word 厚生, which means "welfare".